# Create API using Mule ESB

Tags: api, maven, mule, mule-studio

I have to create an API supplying some relevant information using Mule ESB. In order to do that, I need to communicate with some others API providers (Wikipedia API for example) toobtain information  and craft the JSON response to return the required information.

PS: I use maven to manage my dependencies.

Do you have any ideas fom where to start or the dependencies/Mule components that can help? I'll be thankful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create your own API start with [APIkit](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-platform-for-apis/apikit-tutorial).

Then to consume rest you have two options, leverage the [http connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/http-request-connector) and a [RAML](http://www.raml.org) definition (only applicable if the api to be consumed is REST based) or create your own connector with [devkit](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-connector-devkit/v/3.7/creating-a-rest-connector).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use options provided by Victor. Here some offical documentation:

[Publishing and Consuming APIs with Mule](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/publishing-and-consuming-apis-with-mule)

These options require an intermediate knowledge of the mule. Dont worry, if you dont have time, you can use all java frameworks with mule:

**Publish Basic Rest API(assuming you do not use soap services):**

Create flow with an http-listener + rest component + java entity.

[REST Component basic example](http://training.middlewareschool.com/mule/rest-component/)

Or create a rest service using spring and deploy it in tomcat for example and send request parameters to some jms queue. Create a jms receive component in mule. This receive parameters from queue and passing the data to the next component in order to create a json response and return to spring rest service.

**Consume Rest service**

For example. You could use apache client and create a maven project as library to be used or invoke inside java mule component:

```
    public class MuleComponent {
            public Object executeRestClient(Object muleMessage){

              //based on apache client
              MyRestClientLibrary client = MyRestClientLibrary ();
              client.setUrl("http://wikipedia/rest/service/..");
              Object someParameters = muleMessage.getProperty("someParameter"....
              Object response = client.executeOperation01(someParameters); 
              return response;//data to be used by next component
            }
        }
```

This component could be used by any mule flow who needs to consume data from wikipedia service.

This could be a possible solution:

```
<rest-inbound> -> 

[get request params] -> 
[consume-external-service(rest apache client)]->
[get data from DB or another source] -> 
[build json response] ->

<rest-outbound>
```

Regards.